# Simba Hbase ODBC Driver Performance?

Tags: odbc, salesforce, hbase

I am looking for performance and user experience of using Simba Hbase ODBC Driver.

I am planning to have Hbase on my Linux Server and do insertion , selection and BI queries to this Hbase from my Windows machine using .NET with Simba HBase ODBC driver.

My other option is to do this all in Java using Salesforce Phoenix JDBC driver on same or other Linux box.  Salesforce has very impressive performance stats for its Phoenix JDBC driver but I couldn't find such stats for Simba ODBC driver for Hbase.

.NET is my comfort-zone but if there is a performance overhead using Simba ODBC driver ( which uses Hbase REST API internally) then I am willing to do it in Java using Salesforce Phoenix JDBC driver (which uses Hbase Java Native API).

Thanks, 
Tony